# Can I use codeigniter session cookie data for authentication?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, cookies

I have a CodeIgniter install, which I use for most of the site. I have a /blog folder, in which I have a Wordpress install.

**Goal**: pages inside the /blog will look have the same header as the rest of the site. They'll also have all the features of Wordpress.

For pages inside the /blog folder (running Wordpress), I'm loading the CodeIgniter header view via a file_get_contents() call, since I don't have access to the CI framework from within Wordpress. I prefer not to create another copy of the header view within the Wordpress template, because I'd like to maintain just one file.

**Now here's the problem**: I can't maintain the user's state in Wordpress, because I don't have access to CodeIgniter's session.

Since the call to the header is done via file_get_contents(), the server doesn't have access to the same session as the client (since it is in effect a call from the server).

Is there a way I can transfer the session cookie data into CodeIgniter via the URL? Something like:

```
file_get_contents('http://mydomain.com/header.php?data=SESSIONDATA').
```

Am I even thinking about this the right way? Note that we are obviously on the same domain, just a different folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following links that might be useful:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-code-igniter/
- http://jidd.jimisaacs.com/post/wordigniter-wordpress-codeigniter/